# Building over graves

Tags: fiqh

Why did imam shafi said it is only ' disliked' to build over the graves and not compeletly forbidden as is implied according to some hadiths?

https://www.islamweb.net/emainpage//index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=367924

Comment: You would do well to include or at least identify the hadiths you're talking about rather than just allude to them.

Comment: Also read [ask] and edit your post by using the *edit* link at the bottom.

Comment: Muslim (969) narrated that Abu’l-Hayaaj al-Asadi said: ‘Ali ibn Abi Taalib said to me: “Shall I not send you with the same instructions as the Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) sent me? ‘Do not leave any image without defacing it or any built-up grave without leveling it.’”